# Layout doesn't rotate automatically

Tags: android, layout, orientation

Hi I already made two XML layout file with same name, one in `layout` folder and the other in `layout-land`.

I already add the `configChanges` tag in Manifest, like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Main"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" >
    ...
</activity>
```

The layout won't change automatically after rotating my phone.

But when I started the app in Landscape orientation, it will use the `layout-land` xml and keep using it even after I rotated my phone into portrait. So, there is no error in the landscape code.

I'm using Android 4.1.2 for testing. Is this the problem?

Or do I need to add some code in the Activity class?

Thanks

**[Update]**

I tried this in freshly-made project. But the problem still the same

Comment: do you lock your android screen rotate setting?

Comment: No, the phone rotate just fine. But the app layout doesn't change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `android:configChanges="orientation"`.

Using this attribute means that you will handle the rotation yourself, but you want the OS to handle it for you.

Comment: Wow, never though the solution would be that simple. Thanks a lot

Comment: how about configchanges="screensize" should we remove it as well?